# returning a json object/array to the browser with a rendered view

Tags: php, json, angularjs, laravel-4

Currently my controller does this

```
public function index()
{
    $trainers = $this->trainer->with('user.images', 'types')->get();

    return View::make('trainers.index')
        ->with('trainers', $trainers);
}
```

I am implementing angular on the front end while hopefully still using as much of laravel as possible.  what I want to do is still return the view trainers.index to the user but I want the browser to receive $trainers as a json object that angular can then assign to a scope variable so that angular can do what it does with it.

turning $trainers to json is not the problem

```
$trainers = $this->trainer->with('user.images', 'types')->get()->toJson;
```

works great but if I just return it to the view it just gets lost as the view is rendered and returned to the browser.  Is there a way to pass this variable which is now json to the browser along with the view trainers.index?

edit: I realise that I can return the view and then have angular make a http request to a method that returns a json object but I am hoping it can all be done at once to save on the number of requests that are necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think it's a bad idea, yes, you can put it in your view and then use `angular.fromJSON` or `JSON.parse` on the JSON string returned from your webserver. That will transform it into a JavaScript object that you can use. By doing it this way, you're making your app more or less un-dynamic. It kinda defeats the whole purpose of using Angular in the first place.

Comment: That sounds like all I need to know thanks back to the proper way so